# Is there a one line command for this?

Tags: shell, scripting

How do i get my Machine Name, Kernel Version, Uptime and Current Date shown on one line using a colon as a delimiter ?
I have already tried a few commands but doesnt get displayed in a line

Comment: Would mind be very clear with your question? Which OS are you using for instance? Did you try some google searches?

Comment: uname -v ? i am just looking for a command for shell in a bash file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "$(hostname):$(uname -r):$(uptime | cut -d " " -f 4,5,6):$(date)"
```

Once you know the commands required, you can expand them in a single echo statement formatted as required.